# Flutter Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-analytics, analytics

I already have been through stackoverflow solutions. Nothing is working.
This is my android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://phonepe.mycloudrepo.io/public/repositories/phonepe-intentsdk-android"
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is my app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" apply true
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    // Make sure that you have the Google services Gradle plugin
//    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
//    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.jbullsinfotech.flutter_template"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.jbullsinfotech.flutter_template"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
//    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0"))

    // Add the dependencies for the Crashlytics and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
//    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
//    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")

    // This dependency is downloaded from the Google’s Maven repository.
    // So, make sure you also include that repository in your project's build.gradle file.
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'
    // For Kotlin users also add the Kotlin extensions library for Play In-App Update:
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0'
}

// This must appear at the bottom of the file
//apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

crashlytics is working fine but analytics is giving me this error. Configured app through flutterfire cli. already checked google-services.json. I see no error anywhere. Imported core, cashlytics and analytics but no analytics record not even in debug view.

Answer (score 0):

Did your check the `android/settings.gradle` file

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    // TODO: you may need to update this plugin version if you are using a newer Flutter version.
    id "com.android.application" version "7.4.2" apply false
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).